# how to translate "and or" where clause from sql query to elasticsearch filter

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elastica

I have a WHERE clause in my SQL query, which have to be translated into the elasticsearch bool filter.

here's the where clause:

```
WHERE (
option = "weight" AND value = "50kg"
)
OR (
option = "weight" AND value = "500kg"
)
AND (
option = "magic" AND value = "no"
)
```

I have written the AND filters for inner ANDs of query, but now I need to put them to the bool filter.

Tried to:

```
$boolFilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();
$boolFilter->addShould($innerFilterAnd1);
$boolFilter->addShould($innerFilterAnd2);
$boolFilter->addMust($innerFilterAnd3);
```

returns nothing.

Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks "everybody", but I figured out the solution by myself. 
You can test the case using this gists:

GIST with my search query:
https://gist.github.com/ArFeRR/f69ebe24ddc543b7bffd

So. If you want to filter by your nested object you have to specify it as "type: object" instead of "type: nested".

It's because of this:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#_arrays_of_inner_objects

(the nested type stored as array, and the object type stored as object)